# What is the correct derivation of energy stored in parallel plates capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, voltage, capacitance

I am little confuse in deriving the energy stored in the capacitor. I read two different derivation in totally different way but yet getting the same value.

[image]

**Here they have calculated work done by bringing small of charges and then integrating all the values to get the total work done by the field. But!!**

[image]

[image]

**Here they have consider the whole distribution together**. How can both potential is equal. By the first method potential energy should be more than the second one as in the first method as the charge on the capacitor incresing the electric field is also incresing and the potential energy as well.
**Please someone explain how the potential energy is same in both the cases.**

Comment: Who are 'they'?

Answer (score 0):

You know that the electric field is conservative, so moving charges from infinity into two parallel plates separated by a given distance should require the same energy regardless of how you move the individual charges. If you put them all together into plates first, and then move the plates together should not give a different result than moving the charges one by one into plates that remain at a fixed distance from the beginning. Your intuition that one method should give a larger energy is wrong, but I cannot tell exactly why, because your description of your intuition is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are saying, but the two derivations are equivalent with respect to the the total work required (total potential energy).

In the first derivation the work per unit charge must be integrated over all the charge moved to calculate the total work since the electric field between the plates is not constant.

In the second derivation, where both plates are fully charged, the electric field generated by plate (a) is constant and therefore the work to move plate (b) a distance $d$ from (a) is simply the product of the electric field, total charge on plate (b) and distance moved by plate (b)

In the second derivation, the magnitude of the electric field generated by plate (a), where the charge is considered uniformly distributed over the area $A$, is

$$E= \frac{Q}{2A\epsilon_o}$$

The force (a) exerts on (b) is then

$$F=QE= \frac{Q^2}{2A\epsilon_o}$$

And the work done moving plate (b)

$$W=Fd= \frac{Q^{2}d}{2A\epsilon_o}\tag{1}$$

The capacitance of a parallel plate air capacitor is given by

$$C=\frac{\epsilon_{o}A}{d}\tag{2}$$

Substituting (2) into (1)

$$W=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$$

Which is the same as the first derivation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed true that in the first method both the charge and the electric field strength increase during the charging, but they both start from zero, unlike in the second method in which they maintain constant values while the plates are pulled apart. You shouldn't therefore expect that the *final* energy stored will be greater in the first method; you're not comparing like with like. Indeed both methods are valid – check the maths! – and they give the same value for the stored energy, as they should.